# React how can I filter map function based on multiple keys

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a filter function for my blogsite where I want to sort blog posts based on multiple checkboxes (categories). Currently I am ony able to store the keys for the category in a state, and the current output on the DOM is all the posts from the grapql fetch.

My question is, how can I filter out the blogposts on the DOM that does not include the category ID in them (needs to support multiple categories on the filter)?

This is my code so far. Important thing to note is that a blogpost can contain multiple categories, so the reference from blogposts to a category is in an array.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { useState } from 'react';
import { useStaticQuery, graphql } from "gatsby"
import PreviewPost from './previewPost';

const Blogpostlist = () => {
  const [menuActive, toggleMenu] = useState(false)
  const toggleChecked = () => toggleMenu(value => !value);
  const [filterArray, setFilterArray] = React.useState([])

  const data = useStaticQuery(graphql`
  query AllPosts {
    allSanityPost(sort: {fields: [_createdAt], order: DESC}) {
      edges {
        node {
          _id
          title
          authors {
            id
            image {
              asset {
                url
              }
            }
            name
          }
          mainImage {
            asset {
              url
            }
          }
          _createdAt
          slug {
            current
          }
          textPreview
          categories {
            id
            title
          }
        }
      }
    }
    allSanityCategory {
      edges {
        node {
          title
          id
        }
      }
    }
  }  
  `)

  

  const handleCheckbox = event => {
    //This function stores they keys related to the category which i wish to sort blog posts on
    if (event.target.checked) {
      console.log("checked")
      setFilterArray(filterArray => [...filterArray, event.target.value]);
    }
    else {
      console.log("unChecked");
      filterArray.forEach(function (item, index, object) {
        if (item === event.target.value) {
          object.splice(index, 1);
        }
      });
    }
  }

  return (
    <section className="border-t-2 border-solid border-gray-200 pt-2">
      <div className="flex justify-between">
        <h2>Nyeste innlegg</h2>
        <button onClick={toggleChecked}>
          <svg className="h-6 w-6" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 20 20" fill="currentColor">
            <path d="M5 4a1 1 0 00-2 0v7.268a2 2 0 000 3.464V16a1 1 0 102 0v-1.268a2 2 0 000-3.464V4zM11 4a1 1 0 10-2 0v1.268a2 2 0 000 3.464V16a1 1 0 102 0V8.732a2 2 0 000-3.464V4zM16 3a1 1 0 011 1v7.268a2 2 0 010 3.464V16a1 1 0 11-2 0v-1.268a2 2 0 010-3.464V4a1 1 0 011-1z" />
          </svg>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div className={`${menuActive ? "block" : "hidden"}`}>
        <h3>Filtrer etter kategori</h3>
        <div className="flex justify-around">
          {data.allSanityCategory.edges &&
            data.allSanityCategory.edges.map((categoryItem, i) => (
              <div key={categoryItem.node.id} className="flex items-center">
                <input type="checkbox" value={categoryItem.node.id} onClick={handleCheckbox} class="w-4 mr-2 h-4 checked:bg-blue-600 checked:border-transparent ..." />
                <p className="m-0">{categoryItem.node.title}</p>
              </div>
            ))}
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="flex flex-wrap">
        {data.allSanityPost.edges &&
          data.allSanityPost.edges.map((postItem, i) => (
              <PreviewPost key={postItem.node._id} sanityData={postItem}></PreviewPost>
          ))}
      </div>

    </section>
  )
}

export default Blogpostlist;
```